# NSNull handling for NSManagedObject properties values

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, nsmanagedobject, nsnull

I'm setting values for properties of my `NSManagedObject`, these values are coming from a `NSDictionary` properly serialized from a JSON file. My problem is, that, when some value is `[NSNull null]`, I can't assign directly to the property:

```
    fight.winnerID = [dict objectForKey:@"winner"];
```

this throws a `NSInvalidArgumentException`

```
"winnerID"; desired type = NSString; given type = NSNull; value = <null>;
```

I could easily check the value for `[NSNull null]` and assign `nil` instead:

```
fight.winnerID = [dict objectForKey:@"winner"] == [NSNull null] ? nil : [dict objectForKey:@"winner"];
```

But I think this is not elegant and gets messy with lots of properties to set.

Also, this gets harder when dealing with `NSNumber` properties:

```
fight.round = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[[dict valueForKey:@"round"] unsignedIntegerValue]]
```

The `NSInvalidArgumentException` is now:

```
[NSNull unsignedIntegerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

In this case I have to treat `[dict valueForKey:@"round"]` before making an `NSUInteger` value of it. And the one line solution is gone.

I  tried making a @try @catch block, but as soon as the first value is caught, it jumps the whole @try block and the next properties are ignored.

Is there a better way to handle `[NSNull null]` or perhaps make this entirely different but easier?

Comment: Out of curiosity, in the number case, why are you unwrapping and re-wrapping the number? What's wrong with `fight.round = [dict objectForKey:@"round"]`?

Comment: @KevinBallard Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "round"; desired type = NSNumber; given type = __NSCFString; value = 3.

Comment: If it's an `NSString`, then `-unsignedIntegerValue` won't work, because that method isn't defined on `NSString`. You could use `-integerValue` instead, which is defined on both `NSNumber` and `NSString`.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It might be a little easier if you wrap this in a macro:

```
#define NULL_TO_NIL(obj) ({ __typeof__ (obj) __obj = (obj); __obj == [NSNull null] ? nil : obj; })
```

Then you can write things like

```
fight.winnerID = NULL_TO_NIL([dict objectForKey:@"winner"]);
```

Alternatively you can pre-process your dictionary and replace all `NSNull`s with `nil` before even trying to stuff it into your managed object.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful! Do you recommend a good source to learn more about macros?

Comment: @Lucien: I wish I did, but no. There's a lot of bits of information out there though, so just google for it.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard .... really superb ..... very helpful ..... you are genius ... happy coding !!!!!!

Comment: How could I achieve this in swift?

Comment: found this answer 
func nullToNil(value : Any?) -> Any? {
    if value is NSNull {
        return nil
    } else {
        return value
    }
}

people.age = nullToNil(peopleDict["age"])

Answer (score 8):

Ok, I've just woke up this morning with a good solution. What about this:

Serialize the JSON using the option to receive Mutable Arrays and Dictionaries:

```
NSMutableDictionary *rootDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_receivedData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
...
```

Get a set of keys that have `[NSNull null]` values from the leafDict:

```
NSSet *nullSet = [leafDict keysOfEntriesWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent passingTest:^BOOL(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    return [obj isEqual:[NSNull null]] ? YES : NO;
}];
```

Remove the filtered properties from your Mutable leafDict:

```
[leafDict removeObjectsForKeys:[nullSet allObjects]];
```

Now when you call `fight.winnerID = [dict objectForKey:@"winner"];` winnerID is automatically going to be `(null)` or `nil` as opposed to `<null>` or `[NSNull null]`.

Not relative to this, but I also noticed that it is better to use a `NSNumberFormatter` when parsing strings to NSNumber, the way I was doing was getting `integerValue` from a nil string, this gives me an undesired NSNumber of `0`, when I actually wanted it to be nil.

Before:

```
// when [leafDict valueForKey:@"round"] == nil
fight.round = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[leafDict valueForKey:@"round"] integerValue]]
// Result: fight.round = 0
```

After:

```
__autoreleasing NSNumberFormatter* numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
fight.round = [numberFormatter numberFromString:[leafDict valueForKey:@"round"]];    
// Result: fight.round = nil
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a couple of category methods to strip nulls from a JSON-generated dictionary or array prior to use:

```
@implementation NSMutableArray (StripNulls)

- (void)stripNullValues
{
    for (int i = [self count] - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        id value = [self objectAtIndex:i];
        if (value == [NSNull null])
        {
            [self removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        }
        else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] ||
                 [value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            if (![value respondsToSelector:@selector(setObject:forKey:)] &&
                ![value respondsToSelector:@selector(addObject:)])
            {
                value = [value mutableCopy];
                [self replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:value];
            }
            [value stripNullValues];
        }
    }
}

@end


@implementation NSMutableDictionary (StripNulls)

- (void)stripNullValues
{
    for (NSString *key in [self allKeys])
    {
        id value = [self objectForKey:key];
        if (value == [NSNull null])
        {
            [self removeObjectForKey:key];
        }
        else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] ||
                 [value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            if (![value respondsToSelector:@selector(setObject:forKey:)] &&
                ![value respondsToSelector:@selector(addObject:)])
            {
                value = [value mutableCopy];
                [self setObject:value forKey:key];
            }
            [value stripNullValues];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

It would be nice if the standard JSON parsing libs had this behaviour by default - it's almost always preferable to omit null objects than to include them as NSNulls.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is

```
-[NSObject setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:]
```

In this scenario you could do

```
[fight setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dict];
```

In the header NSKeyValueCoding.h it defines that "Dictionary entries whose values are NSNull result in `-setValue:nil forKey:key` messages being sent to the receiver.

The only downside is you will have to transform any keys in the dictionary to keys that are in the receiver. i.e.

```
dict[@"winnerID"] = dict[@"winner"];
[dict removeObjectForKey:@"winner"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same problem, found this post, did it in a slightly different way.Using category only though -

Make a new category file for "NSDictionary" and add this one method -

```
@implementation NSDictionary (SuperExtras)

- (id)objectForKey_NoNSNULL:(id)aKey
{
    id result = [self objectForKey:aKey];

if(result==[NSNull null])
{
    return nil;
}

return result;

}

@end
```

Later on to use it in code, for properties that can have NSNULL in them just use it this way -

```
newUser.email = [loopdict objectForKey_NoNSNULL:@"email"];
```

Thats it