# CoreData Prevent against NSNull

Tags: objective-c, json

I have a core data field that is a String which is optional. Sometimes in my json response I will get back null. If I don't do the following code check below, the program crashes. Is there a better way to do this?

```
story.author = [newsStory valueForKeyPath:@"author_title"] != [NSNull null] ? [newsStory valueForKeyPath:@"author_title"] : @"Staff Writer";
```

Comment: You can wrap the check into a Maccro.

possibly repost : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137920/nsnull-handling-for-nsmanagedobject-properties-values

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSNull handling for NSManagedObject properties' values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137920/nsnull-handling-for-nsmanagedobject-properties-values)

Answer (score 0):

You way looks good. If you end up using this idiom a lot you may to set the default value for this attribute to "Staff Writer" in your data model in Xcode.

Note as of Mac OS X 10.5 you can replace `[newsStory valueForKeyPath:@"author_title"]` with the easier to read dot syntax `newsStory.author_title`. The two statements use exactly the same code paths as described in the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001803-SW4).